# How to allow multiple UICollectionViewCells to be selected and deselected?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UICollectionView` (with `.allowsMultipleSelection = true`), and I want it so that whenever I tap on a cell, it changes color, and when I tap it again, it reverts to its old color. I understand that `UICollectionViewCell`s have a `isSelected` property, so I've tried manipulating that to change the colors.

```
override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if isSelected == false {
                contentView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
                roleLabel.textColor = .gray
            } else {
                contentView.backgroundColor = .gray
                roleLabel.textColor = .black
                print("selected")
            }
        }
    }
```

My the view controller class that contains the collection view in question has defined `didSelectItemAt`. However, whenever I tap on the cell, "selected" is printed each time - meaning regardless of how many times I've tapped on the cell, it still sets `isSelected` to be `true` each time - and the color doesn't change. Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you make sure that, after selecting a cell A , then selecting another cell B, then trying to deselecting cell A works for you or not ?

Comment: I tried that, it still keeps selecting A again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to Store your selected cell in array.for example just store indexpath of selected Cell in Array than Check if indexpath is Already present in Array that means it is Already Selected.

```
var slectedCell = [IndexPath]()

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {


        if slectedCell.contains(indexPath) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
            slectedCell = slectedCell.filter { $0 != indexPath }
        }
        else {
            slectedCell.append(indexPath)
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }

    }


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        if slectedCell.contains(indexPath) {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray
        }
        else {
            cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        }


    }
```